create d3 heatmap showing days on one axis and hours on the other?
I want to create a heatmap with d3 showing days (January 1, January 2, etc.) on one axis, and hours (12am, 1am, 2am, etc.) on the other. I have managed to get the data to display, but I'm not sure if it's right. I also can't figure out how to get the ticks showing the days/hours. I know tickFormat should probably be used, but I'm not sure how. Any help would be supremely appreciated.


const margin = { top: 130, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 130 },
            width = 650 - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = 650 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        const svg = d3.select("#viz")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform",
                "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        const parseTime = d3.utcParse("%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p");
        const formatHours = d3.timeFormat("%H%M")
        const formatYears = d3.timeFormat("%m/%Y")

        let minDate, maxDate;

        const x = d3.scaleTime()
            .range([0, width])
        svg.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
            .call(d3.axisTop(x))

        const y = d3.scaleTime()
            .range([0, height])
            .domain([0, 2359])

        svg.append("g")
            .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

        const color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
            .range(["#fff000", "purple", "blue", "green"])

        d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sprucegoose1/sample-data/main/subway_delays.csv").then((data) => {
            data.forEach((d) => {
                d.day = parseTime(d.Date)
                d.hour = +formatHours(d.day)
            })

            let allDates = d3.extent(data, d => d.day)

            x.domain(allDates)

            svg.selectAll()
                .data(data)
                .enter()
                .append("rect")
                .attr("x", d => x(d.day))
                .attr("y", d => y(d.hour))
                .attr("width", 2)
                .attr("height", 2)
                .style("fill", d => color(d.Affected))

        })
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.8.5/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="viz"></div>




Looking at your code, you've defined your y time scale with a domain of .domain([0, 2359]).  For a time scale, d3 would expect a date object (or coerce what you give it to a date object) and I don't think 2359 will be handled properly.   So, what is your expectation?  Since your data has many days, the y-axis scale should represent the hour regardless of the day?

@Mark Thanks. Yes, I want the y-axis to represent the hour regardless of the day.

I think you have two options.

The first is to have the y-scale represent the number of seconds each data point is into its respective day.  The y-scale then becomes a simple linear scale like:
const y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([0, height])
  .domain([0, 86400]); //<-- number of seconds in a day

For this to work, you'll need to add a property into the data for each point that calculates its "seconds into the day":
data.forEach((d) => {
  d.day = parseTime(d.Date);
    d.numberOfSecondsIntoDay =
        d.day.getHours() * 60 * 60 +
        d.day.getMinutes() * 60 +
        d.day.getSeconds();
});

With this approach, by default, you'd end up with a y-axis showing an integer "number of seconds" value.   So, you'd then need a custom formatter to convert that to HH:MM:SS (or something else).  Code borrowed from here:
svg.append('g').call(
  d3.axisLeft(y).tickFormat((v) => {
    return new Date(1000 * v).toISOString().substr(11, 8);
  })
);

Putting everything together:


<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.8.5/d3.min.js"></script>
    <div id="viz"></div>

    <script>
      const margin = { top: 60, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 60 },
        width = 650 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 650 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

      const svg = d3
        .select('#viz')
        .append('svg')
        .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append('g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

      const parseTime = d3.utcParse('%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p');

      let minDate, maxDate;

      const x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
      svg.append('g').attr('transform', 'translate(0,0)').call(d3.axisTop(x));

      const y = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, height]).domain([0, 86400]);

      svg.append('g').call(
        d3.axisLeft(y).tickFormat((v) => {
          return new Date(1000 * v).toISOString().substr(11, 8);
        })
      );

      const color = d3
        .scaleOrdinal()
        .range(['#fff000', 'purple', 'blue', 'green']);

      d3.csv(
        'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sprucegoose1/sample-data/main/subway_delays.csv'
      ).then((data) => {
        data.forEach((d) => {
          d.day = parseTime(d.Date);
          d.numberOfSecondsIntoDay =
            d.day.getHours() * 60 * 60 +
            d.day.getMinutes() * 60 +
            d.day.getSeconds();
        });

        let allDates = d3.extent(data, (d) => d.day);

        x.domain(allDates);

        svg
          .selectAll()
          .data(data)
          .enter()
          .append('rect')
          .attr('x', (d) => x(d.day))
          .attr('y', (d) => y(d.numberOfSecondsIntoDay))
          .attr('width', 2)
          .attr('height', 2)
          .style('fill', (d) => color(d.Affected));
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>



I think this approach is programmatically cleaner but you lose the nice logical "time" ticks on the y-axis.

The second is to continue to use a time scale on the y-axis but coerce all the date times to just times on a single day.  In this example I lop off the time and make all the data points occur on the epoch day of Jan 1st, 1970.  So the scale becomes:
const y = d3.scaleTime()
  .range([0, height])
  .domain([new Date(0), new Date(86400 * 1000)]); //<-- first day of epoch

The data manipulation is then:
data.forEach((d) => {
  d.day = parseTime(d.Date);
  d.justTimePart = new Date(
    (d.day.getHours() * 60 * 60 +
     d.day.getMinutes() * 60 +
     d.day.getSeconds()) * 1000)
  });

At this point, you'll see some strangeness with the default tick formatter.  It'll show you the year and day on those boundaries.   So again let's use a custom format:
 svg.append('g').call(
   d3.axisLeft(y).
     tickFormat(d3.utcFormat("%I %p")) //<-- American style AM/PM
 );

Putting this one all together:


<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.8.5/d3.min.js"></script>
    <div id="viz"></div>

    <script>
      const margin = { top: 60, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 60 },
        width = 650 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 650 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

      const svg = d3
        .select('#viz')
        .append('svg')
        .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append('g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

      const parseTime = d3.utcParse('%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p');

      let minDate, maxDate;

      const x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
      svg.append('g').attr('transform', 'translate(0,0)').call(d3.axisTop(x));

      const y = d3.scaleTime().range([0, height]).domain([new Date(0), new Date(86400 * 1000)]);

      svg.append('g').call(
        d3.axisLeft(y).
          tickFormat(d3.utcFormat("%I %p"))
      );

      const color = d3
        .scaleOrdinal()
        .range(['#fff000', 'purple', 'blue', 'green']);

      d3.csv(
        'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sprucegoose1/sample-data/main/subway_delays.csv'
      ).then((data) => {
        data.forEach((d) => {
          d.day = parseTime(d.Date);
          d.justTimePart = new Date(
            (d.day.getHours() * 60 * 60 +
            d.day.getMinutes() * 60 +
            d.day.getSeconds()) * 1000)
        });

        let allDates = d3.extent(data, (d) => d.day);

        x.domain(allDates);

        svg
          .selectAll()
          .data(data)
          .enter()
          .append('rect')
          .attr('x', (d) => x(d.day))
          .attr('y', (d) => y(d.justTimePart))
          .attr('width', 2)
          .attr('height', 2)
          .style('fill', (d) => color(d.Affected));
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>



I prefer this approach as it retains the help d3 gives you on making a nicely formatted y-axis.

Thanks so much for your thoughtful answer and showing the two different approaches! I agree with your preference for the second.
